# Google Maps Autocomplete not loading in Rails app

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to get Google Maps autocomplete for addresses working. This is the snippet of code I'm using:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key=<%=ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY'] %>&libraries=places"></script>

<label for="locationTextField">Location</label>
<input id="locationTextField" type="text" size="50">

<script>
  function init() {
    var input = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
```

I've put this inside one of my views and while everything appears to load fine (no console errors), when I type in an address, the dropdown list never appears.

That dropdown box is in a `.pac-container` div, which does appear, though `display:none;` when I override that in Chrome dev tools, I just see the google logo appear below my search box (as if the list is empty).

I copied this code to a blank html page outside of my rails app and it worked fine.

Comment: Check this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Comment: I was originally using their first example - Autocomplete for address forms. I had the same problem using their exact code.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me.

I tested this:

```
<style> #map {height: 90%} </style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<label for="locationTextField">Location</label>
<input id="locationTextField" type="text" size="50">
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
   function init() {
    var input = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 50.869754630095834, lng: 4.353812903165801},
      zoom: 12
    }); 
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
```

Is there anything you are doing different?  Anything I'm missing?